# Plot Large scale and Small scale fading with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The below figure shows large scale and small scale fading concepts in communication.

[image: 1]

Please also see my MWE:

```
\documentclass[borders=1mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes}

\makeatletter
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{invgauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathln{#1}% <- might need parsing
  \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmathresult}{-2}%
  \pgfmathsqrt@{\pgfmathresult}%
  \let\@radius=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathmultiply{6.28318531}{#2}% <- might need parsing
  \pgfmathdeg@{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmathcos@{\pgfmathresult}%
  \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfmathresult}{\@radius}%
}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{randnormal}{0}{%
  \pgfmathrnd@
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0.0pt\relax%
    \def\pgfmathresult{0.00001}%
  \fi%
  \let\@tmp=\pgfmathresult%
  \pgfmathrnd@%
  \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0.0pt\relax%
    \def\pgfmathresult{0.00001}%
  \fi
  \pgfmathinvgauss@{\pgfmathresult}{\@tmp}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[-latex](0,0)--++(6.75,0);
\draw[-latex](0,0)--++(0,5.5);

\draw[domain=0:6.25,smooth,variable=\x,Blue] plot ({\x},{-0.8*\x+5});
\draw[domain=0:6.25,smooth,variable=\x,Green] plot ({\x},{(-0.8*\x+5)+0.6*randnormal});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:
[image]

How can I add small scale  effect to my plot with Tikz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution using `pgfplots`.

- I used `sin(150*x)+cos(110*x)+cos(220*x)` as the large scale effect function.
- For small scale effect, `rnd*sin(5000*x)` function is used. `rnd` returns a random value between 0 and 1.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=0:6.25,red] {-0.8*x+5};
\addplot[domain=0:6.25,black,samples=300,smooth,dashed] {-0.8*x+5+sin(150*x)+cos(110*x)+cos(220*x)};
\addplot[domain=0:6.25,blue,samples=300,smooth] {-0.8*x+5+sin(150*x)+cos(110*x)+cos(220*x)+0.3*rnd*sin(5000*x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```